# How to query list of objects with paramteres that might not be entered?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, parameters

I'm trying to query list of objects filtered by parameters that might not get entered by the user at all.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT  * " +
        "FROM project  " +
        "WHERE CASE WHEN (:location is not null) THEN location_Id LIKE :location" +
        " and CASE WHEN (:category is not null) THEN category_Id LIKE :category", nativeQuery = true)
List<Project> getProjects(@Param("category") List<Category> category,
                          @Param("location") List<Location> location);
```

But i keep on getting similar errors that my syntax is wrong even tho i just copied it from a tutorial. Any idea where i might be mistaking?

Comment: Can you post that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single query:

```
WHERE (:location is null OR location_Id LIKE :location) AND
      (:category is null OR category_Id LIKE :category)
```

From a performance perspective, `OR` can kill performance (by preventing the use of available indexes).  Often applications build the `WHERE` clause for the non-`NULL` parameter values.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I want to filter project by category if there is a parameter set else i don't want to do anything with it (same goes with location).

Comment: @aratata . . . That is what this expression does.